# Treat value as state in Compose function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In my Composable function I have condition what decides what label should be displayed.

```
 var likedLabel = if (post.likedByUser) "Liked" else "Like"
```

On click I want change value of post.likedByUser

```
onClick = {
    post.likedByUser = !post.likedByUser;
},
```

I expect label in my Text will update automatically but it doesn't. Why? I tried solution with MutableLiveData but the same result

```
Text(
       likedLabel,
          modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(reactionText) {
              start.linkTo(reactionIcon.end, margin = 2.dp)
              top.linkTo(reactionIcon.top)
              bottom.linkTo(reactionIcon.bottom)
       }
  )
```

Comment: post must be a livedata or flow type, and you have to observe it's value from composable

Comment: make that post a liveData in a viewmodel and observe state from that livedata; with that you can be able to update if the post is liked or not from anywhere in the composable heirarchy and update the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In compose, we don't need to mess around with LiveData objects.

```
var likedLabel by remember {
     mutableStateOf (
         if (post.likedByUser) "Liked" else "Like"
     )
}
```

```
onClick = {
    post.likedByUser = !post.likedByUser;
    likedLabel = if (post.likedByUser) "Liked" else "Like"
},
```

Let the rest of the code be the same

Comment: If the posting depends on network calls, you can mutate the likeLable inside a callback to check if the posting succeeded.